# Luks "No key available with this passphrase" but seemingly at random

Tags: linux, encryption, arch-linux, luks, passphrase

I've been having the strangest of experiences with my encrypted Luks volume and was hoping maybe someone could help me shed some light on it. Let me walk you through it.

When installing my OS (vanilla Arch (btw)) I set up an encrypted root partition (`/boot` is left unencrypted) using cryptestup & luks v2. Everything working fine for the first few days without issue. Then one day after a reboot suddenly it won't accept my passphrase anymore.

`No key available with this passphrase` is all I get. So the first thing I checked was obviously whether there was anything funky with my keyboard layout. Booted up a live Manjaro ISO to mount the volume in there with the following command so I could see my password (no mistyping it this way):

`echo [mypassword] | cryptsetup open --test-passphrase /dev/nvme0n1p2`

and also tried the following in case it made a difference

`echo [mypassword] | cryptsetup luksOpen --test-passphrase /dev/nvme0n1p2`

but to no avail. Booted up using `break=premount` to check my keyboard layout during the startup, and there's also no issue with it. So at this point I thought I was sol seeing as I didn't have a header backup (thinking the current ones got corrupted), but in a last ditch effort born of desperation I tried to boot again, and this time it worked fine?

Immediately went ahead and created a header backup file. Verified it was intact by running

`echo [mypassword] | cryptsetup luksOpen --test-passphrase ./luksHeader`

and saved the header outside of the encrypted volume.

I haven't run into the issue again until today, where again during boot I got the `No key available with this passphrase` message. Alrighty then, boot up to my live ISO and try to mount the volume there, doesn't work. Then I copy the headers from the place I had stored them and try to open them, but that **ALSO doesn't work**. Even ran the command that makes it impossible to mess up my password:

`echo [mypassword] | cryptsetup luksOpen --test-passphrase ./luksHeader`

To rule out acute selective amnesia with regards to my password, I attempted to open up the header file on a different machine, and it works no problem. Meanwhile on my main machine I'm still getting the error.

So I decided to spam the command basically, running

`echo [mypassword] | cryptsetup luksOpen --test-passphrase ./luksHeader`

as soon as the previous finishes. Oddly enough, I'm now observing about a 1/5 success chance for opening the header file. Most of the time I would get multiple fails in a row, but sometimes I would get 2 or 3 successes in a row as well.

**This struck me as extremely odd seeing as the above command makes it impossible to mistype/misremember the password. It was always the same string being passed to the header file. Furthermore, this is not a constant issue as I mentioned, since between the first time I was able to observe this and today, there were multiple weeks where I could restart & enter my passphrase without issue.**

I then tried the same thing with the encrypted partition and was also able to observe about a 1/5 success rate. I then decided to reboot, got the `No key available ...` message twice while entering my password, and succeeded to boot on my 3rd attempt.

---

If you've made it this far, congratulations. I hope you haven't gone as insane reading this as I have experiencing this.

As it stands right now, I'm not at all worried about losing my data, since a) I have backups of everything important and b) I can always decrypt my drive on another device (I think, lol), but I would nonetheless like an explanation for the strange behavior I'm witnessing, and potentially a solution to it, since at the very least it provides a potential annoyance to me not being able to boot whenever I want.

I've even considered some outlandish things like cosmic background radiation, or other sources of electromagnetic fields, and if none of you can come up with a better theory then that I suppose I'll have to test it by moving my tower into the same room as the machine that can decrypt the header without failure.

The big problem is that this issue seems to occur randomly, as I have yet to figure out a way to reliably reproduce it. If you could even aid me in that, it would be greatly appreciated!

Lastly: This issue seems to be unaffected by additional reboots / poweroffs as I could not observe any improvement on the reliability of me opening the header file / the volume. The only thing that seems to affect it is time (tomorrow it will be fine probably). I did not check clearing the CMOS though since I don't want to lose my BIOS cofniguration if it can be avoided.

Comment: random failures suggests hardware failure.  Could be cpu fail, memory fail, or some bus in between the cpu and the device is faliing, or very possibly the disk.

Comment: @user10489 hard drive I don't think, it's brand new and has no corrupted sectors. plus the problem also occurs with the header backup as mentioned, read from an external storage drive. CPU or memory could be, how would you go about verifying that?

Comment: If the cpu is failing, other things should be crashing, but sometimes you aren't lucky enough for it to be that obvious.  Tools like memtest86 can test the memory pretty well.  If your hardware has a manual self test (something deeper than POST) that might help.   It still could be the hard drive -- maybe not the disk but the controller itself.  Or you could have a controller with a firmware bug that only fails in special corner cases or something annoying.